# Destructing lint error even when Destructing

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am getting linting errors as follows. Why is this occurring even when I destruct?

> error    Must use destructuring props assignment
> react/destructuring-assignment

The lines with issues.

```
const { imageName, header, description } = props.cardContentData || {};

const { description, content = [] } = props.cardData || {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it out as follows. It is complaining about destructuring on the `props.cardData`.

```
  const { cardData } = props;
  const { description, content = [] } = cardData || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the linter wants you to write

```
const { cardContentData: { imageName, header, description } = {} } = props;
const { cardData: { description, content = [] } = {} } = props;
```

or in a single statement

```
const {
  cardContentData: { imageName, header, description } = {},
  cardData: { description, content = [] } = {},
} = props;
```

Notice that unlike your original code that uses `||`, defaulting the `props` properties to `{}` only works when they're `undefined`, not other falsy values (in particular `null`).